# Is it possible to extend javascript language server

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol, typescript-language-server

Lets say I would like to extend the javascript language server in order to allow the following import syntax:

`from 'file' import {a b c}`

With that syntax it would be possible to get autocompletion on the file path as well as on the import things.

Is there a way to do that without creating a whole new language server or parser or compiler?

Comment: You need to create parser or compiler which understand your custom syntax